# Alternative way to detect changed select option in Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a form where the user is supposed to enter a lot of repeated instances of data, and I want the user to be able to do so with a minimal effort. It is somewhat similar to a wizard.

I wish that the user does not need to click a separate button when all input and selections are done for one instance, but instead that the form submits automatically when the form is completed.

I use knockout, with the `options` binding. My current approach is to use a knockout `computed`, which checks all the fields in the form and automatically submits when all fields have valid value.

My actual form and validation code is a bit complex, but this simplified example shows what i am trying to achieve:

```
<input type="text" id="theText" data-bind="value: text" />
<select id="theSelect" data-bind="options: options, value: selected, optionsText: 'text', optionsCaption: 'Please select'">
</select>
<div id="added" data-bind="foreach: added">
    <span data-bind="text: text"></span>:<span data-bind="text: selected.text"></span><br/>
</div>
```

And the corresponding javascript:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this; 

    this.text = ko.observable(''); 
    this.selected = ko.observable(null); 
    this.added = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.options = [{value: 1, text: "Number one"}, {value: 2, text: "Number two"}, {value: 3, text: "Number three"}]; 

    this.add = ko.computed(function() {
        var text = self.text(); 
        var selected = self.selected(); 
        if (text !== '' && selected) {
            self.added.push({
                text: text, 
                selected: selected
            }); 
            self.text(''); 
            self.selected(null); 
        }
    }); 
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvaK8/1/) showing this example. When both the text field and the select have value, a new row is added underneath them and they are reset to empty.

This approach more or less works, but it is a bit magical. It also have given me some problems when i try to make this form usable with only keyboard (to enable higher working speed for the user).

For an example of problem with this approach, try to enter something in the textbox and move to the select using the tab key. Then try to change the selected value with the key arrows. Since this will fire the change event, the first option will be selected immediately. [I have another question about this specific problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298843/selecting-option-value-with-arrow-keys-and-enter-in-knockout-js)

Is there a better way to achieve the auto-submit-when-everything-is-valid in knockout?

I am not asking for a complete solution on the problem with the arrow key selection, but rather just for some alternative starting points for me to work with. Alternatives to `ko.computed()`.

Comment: Your approach looks technically solid to me. What are your reservations about this? Also, if you're mainly after whether this is good UX or not, you may have better luck at our sister site [UX.StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Jeroen This approach is solid in this simple example. As long as the user is using the mouse to click on the select, and then click on the correct option. But when i try to add possibilities to navigate with only keyboard, i get stuck.

Comment: You might want to add a `hasFocus` attribute for when the text input is empty to autofocus it.  For the keyboard usability, you need to add a submit button, otherwise tabbing over to the select and pressing down is submitting it.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand The actual form use the `hasfocus` binding for all elements, but i tried to strip down the example to the essentials.

Comment: I know you have two questions up on this topic but the problem you are having is a very 'niche' problem that is hard to give advice on without doing a lot of leg work for you.  Have you considered creating your own custom binding handler for this issue?  I think this would be a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay launching `computed` by extending it with `throttle` extender. It means that user will have a certain amount of time to select appropriate option by up/down keys before `computed` function will run.

```
this.add = ko.computed(function() {
    var text = self.text(); 
    var selected = self.selected(); 
    if (text !== '' && selected) {
        self.added.push({
            text: text, 
            selected: selected
        }); 
        self.text(''); 
        self.selected(null); 
    }
}).extend({ throttle: 1000 });
```

1 sec will be enough to switch between options since the throttle timer will be reset after every keypress. You can try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LvaK8/3/).

P.S. I do not claim my answer as valuable, but it is what I think about possible improvements for your form. Also I think my improvement will be good for dropdowns with small amount of options only (max. 7-10).

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about _alternative_ ways to detect change. But i appreciate the answer, it actually pointed me in the right direction for another problem i have been dodging for a few days now.